# Socket.IO. '/' namespace

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, namespaces

I have some misunderstanding with Socket.IO. In official documentation it is said, that `io.emit('an event sent to all connected clients')` will send message to all connected clients. And it seems to have logic, since `io.emit()` sends message to all clients, connected to '/' namespace, and all clients are automatically connected to this namespace (even if I connnect to `/protected` namespace on the client). I am connecting to '/protected' namespace on the client side. I have to `connection` handlers on the server side, one for `'/'` namespace, one for `'/protected'`. When I am connecting to `'/protected'`,  `'/'` handler is also fired. When I have tried to print socket `server.nsps` object it seems to have two namepaces:

```
{ '/':
    Namespace {
    name: '/',
        server:
    Server {
        nsps: [Circular],
            _path: '/socket.io',
            _serveClient: true,
            _adapter: [Function: Adapter],
        _origins: '*:*',
            sockets: [Circular],
            eio: [Object],
            httpServer: [Object],
            engine: [Object] },
    sockets:
    { '/#hc8Vg0RiP-CdmHE5AAAA': [Object],
        '/#pZuHkVmTI6ZmJ4ADAAAB': [Object] },
    connected:
    { '/#hc8Vg0RiP-CdmHE5AAAA': [Object],
        '/#pZuHkVmTI6ZmJ4ADAAAB': [Object] },
    fns: [],
        ids: 0,
        adapter:
    Adapter {
        nsp: [Circular],
            rooms: [Object],
            sids: [Object],
            encoder: Encoder {} } },
    '/protected':
    Namespace {
    name: '/protected',
        server:
    Server {
        nsps: [Circular],
            _path: '/socket.io',
            _serveClient: true,
            _adapter: [Function: Adapter],
        _origins: '*:*',
            sockets: [Object],
            eio: [Object],
            httpServer: [Object],
            engine: [Object] },
    sockets:
    { '/protected#hc8Vg0RiP-CdmHE5AAAA': [Object],
        '/protected#pZuHkVmTI6ZmJ4ADAAAB': [Object] },
    connected:
    { '/protected#hc8Vg0RiP-CdmHE5AAAA': [Object],
        '/protected#pZuHkVmTI6ZmJ4ADAAAB': [Object] },
    fns: [],
        ids: 0,
        adapter:
    Adapter {
        nsp: [Circular],
            rooms: [Object],
            sids: [Object],
            encoder: Encoder {} },
    _events: { connection: [Function] },
    _eventsCount: 1 },}
```

As you can see, there are some connections in both namespaces. And I have such code on server side

```
io.of('/protected').on('message',function(msg){

  io.emit('server_message',{message: msg + ' server'});
})
```

Nothing happens on client side. And I do not understand why.

Comment: Can you post the relevant client side code?

Comment: I am using React and redux -saga, so it can be hard to understand. Nothing special in my code.     function connect() {
  const socket = io('/all');
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log(socket.connected);
    socket.on('connect', () => {

      const token = getAuthToken();
      socket.emit(authClientEvents.AUTHENTICATE, {token: token});
      resolve(socket);
    });
  });
}

Comment: ROFL, isn't part of the point of using a framework to make the code *easier* to understand? So, you're connecting to an 'all' namespace on the client? Any error message on the client side from that?